# Generate a List of Unique Random Numbers

Tags: java, random, numbers, unique

So, I have a random number generator, where it generates 10 numbers between 1 and whatever the user inputs as the maximum. It worked well, but I want to make it so it doesn't generate duplicate numbers. So, if it generates a 5, none of the other numbers can be 5.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Usually, people would tag the language rather than include it in the title. (Will edit for him)

Comment: One solution could be to use Set instead of list. If it generates a duplicate. set will just ignore it and you can again generate a new number. Continue this until the Set size has not reached the limit i.e. 10 numbers in your case.

Answer (score 3):

You can try rejection sampling. Begin with an empty set. Generate a number, if it is in the set, try again. That is to say keep picking until you find a number not in the set. Once you find a new number add it to the set and then return it to the user.

Of course if a large amount of numbers have been generated, say k and the upper bound is n, then the time to get a new number follows a geometric distribution (with success probability (n-k)/n), so the expected number of samplings required before you find a unique number is n/(n-k).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a small maximum, you can use Collection.shuffle() a list of unique values.  From this you can select 10 elements.

Comment: The maximums will always vary from the program I'm making. I could be anywhere from 5 to 50. And also, it's actually picking random letters, I'm just getting it to get a string's char at the position of the random number.

Comment: The range has to be the same or larger than the number you want to select. You can't get 10 unique values with a maximum range of less than 10.  e.g. 5.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the first to ask this question.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-to-generate-a-list-of-unique-random-strings for a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that the number is not a duplicate, store the found numbers in Java SET so that adds only if there is no duplicate inside it.

Algorith for random generation can be something like:

```
take the system time as your seed value 
use this to get the random numbers
suppose user says number between 1-100
so take system milliseconds%100 so time always  changes so maximum probability that you get random numbers.
```

So, always take the seed value mod(%) your upper bound in this case its 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0, r = 0;
    boolean ch = true;
    int[] list = new int[num];
    while (i < num)
    {
        r = rnd.nextInt(num);
        ch = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (r == list[j])
            {
                ch = false;
                break;
            }
        if (ch)
        {
            list[i] = r;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: add few points on explaining what code does and the control points.